# Is it possible to set random order IDs?

Tags: commerce

Is it possible, in Drupal Commerce, to give random order IDs to orders, similarly to what the ["Advanced Ordernumbers for VirtueMart" plugin](https://open-tools.net/documentation/ordernumber-plugin-for-virtuemart.html) does?

With that plugin, it is possible to use a template for the ID, which determines the number of fixed and random numbers/characters, for example to make the order ID a 9-alphanumeric identifier like *BC54R4UYD*. Naturally, an order ID should be unique and should not be given to another order.